# dentry_path_raw not working C

Tags: c, linux, security, kernel

So, I'm trying to compile this code that I have to try and "hide" a file (doing this for my security class) and I can't seem to get it working, it seems that `linux/fs.h` has removed/depreciated `dentry_path_raw`? Do you guys know how to fix this by any chance?

`magic = dentry_path_raw(fp->f_dentry,filename,INTERNAL_BUFFER_LEN);`

and it throws this error on build

`error: implicit declaration of function ‘dentry_path_raw’`

Comment: Bump, can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are not including explicitly the header that declares the function and the compiler is 'including' implicitily for you and this throws a warning. You could try to add: `#include <linux/proc_fs.h>`

More, `create_proc_read_entry` is a deprecated function. Have a look [here](http://lkml.org/lkml/2013/4/11/215)

Comment: I included #include <linux/proc_fs.h> into it but dentry_path_raw seems to be depreciated/removed which is why. Do you know what I could change it to?